# Mathjax configuration latex to center

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I'm trying to use mathjax-node in javascript.

as you can see in picture, I want to make tex to center not left.

[this is rendered picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liQmO.png)

is there any configuration on mathjax-node?

I tried text-align and displayAlign to center, but it doesn't worked.

```
function convert(tex, options, callback) {
    mathjax.typeset({
        width: options.width,
        ex: 10,
        math: tex,
        format: "TeX",
        // style: "text-align: center;",
        svg: true, // SVG output
        linebreaks: true,
    }, function (data) {
        if (data.errors) return callback(data.errors);
        callback(undefined, data.svg);
    });
}


const mathjax = require('mathjax-node');
mathjax.config({
    TeX: {
        extensions: ["color.js"]
    },
    MathJax: {
        displayAlign: "center",
        // 'text-align': "center"
        extensions: ["TeX/color.js"],
        'fast-preview':{disabled:false}
    },
});
mathjax.start();
```

this is code of mathjax.typeset and config

Comment: Do you want the TeX to be inline or block?

Comment: um does it have differences?

Comment: this is steps in latex to svg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing MathJax in display mode, MathJax will automatically center the MathJax code for you.

> To print your equations in display mode use one of these delimiters: [ ... ], \begin{displaymath} ... \end{displaymath} or \begin{equation} ... \end{equation}. $$ ... $$ is discouraged as it can give inconsistent spacing, and may not work well with some math packages.

```html
<p>
The mass-energy equivalence is described by the famous equation
\[ E=mc^2 \]
discovered in 1905 by Albert Einstein. 
In natural units (\(c = 1 \)), the formula expresses the identity
\begin{equation}
E=m
\end{equation}
</p>

<script type="text/javascript" async  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.7/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>
```

The above example and quote is derived from [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Learn_LaTeX_in_30_minutes).

This a very quick way of centering the Math as no extra configuration is required.